# create method findViewById'int in android'

Tags: android

Hi everyone while declearning Button and setContentView inside  method, I am get **"create method findViewById ('int')"** message , as a newbie in Android.. I tried to sort it through different method but cnt fix . Here is my code:

```
                                public class DisplayVideo {
static int getWidth;

public static void startVideo() {
    final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getWidth = Main.width;
            if (getWidth > 1000) {
                setContentView(R.layout.lesson_large);
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.lesson);
            }
            // @@@ FOR INTRO AV @@@//
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            MediaController mediaControler = new MediaController(null);
            mediaControler.setAnchorView(videoView);
            Uri introVideo = Uri.parse(statics.urlAv + "AV264.MP4");
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaControler);
            videoView.setVideoURI(introVideo);
            videoView.start();

            // menu();
            // exit();

            // @@@ FOR LESSON/SUBLESSSON AV @@@//
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                            MediaController mediaControler = new MediaController(
                                    null);
                            mediaControler.setAnchorView(videoView);
                            Uri video = Uri.parse(statics.urlAv
                                    + "AV264.MP4");
                            videoView.setMediaController(mediaControler);
                            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                            videoView.start();

                            // menu();
                            // exit();
                        }
                    });

        }

    });
}
```

}

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cant get the resource of Button without `setContentView()`, without set the ContentView application not able to know of which xml(layout) this Button refers to?
or you can create a dynamic button and layout for doing the above operation

Comment: Thank You for you kind response...any way to get the Button on method by declaring setContentView

Comment: refer this for an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241145/creating-linearlayout-in-java-elements-are-not-shown/7241274#7241274