# ListView containing ListView

Tags: android, listview

I need to display a listView containing another listView.

Here's how I do it to show the first listView :

```
    public class myClas extends ListActivity {

        private List<Order> listOrders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orderList, orderItems;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        /**
         * First method called when the activity is created
         * @param Bundle savedInstanceState contains the backup status recorded during the last execution of the activity
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_historic);

            //hashmap
            orderList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            orderItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //loading in the background
            new LoadingOrders().execute();
        }

        /**
         * Loading orders in the background
         * */
        class LoadingOrders extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting the thread in the background, a progress bar is displayed
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Historic.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Retrieving orders
             * */
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
//the first listView                
for (int i = 0; i < listOrders.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("date", "date_exemple);
                    orderList.add(map);

//the second listView  
                    for (int j = 0; j < order.getOrderItems().size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> mapItems = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        mapItems.put("textViewPrice", "price_exemple"));
                        mapItems.put("textViewStatus", "status_example");
                        orderList.add(map);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing the background tasks, remove the progress bar
             * **/
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                //The progress bar is removed
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // Update the user interface
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//the first listView  
                        //Updating orders
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MyClass.this, orderList,
                                R.layout.order, new String[] { "date"},
                                new int[] { R.id.textViewDate});
                        setListAdapter(adapter);

//the second listView  
                        //OrderItems
                        **adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MyClass.this, orderItems,
                                R.layout.order_item, new String[] { "textViewPrice", "textViewStatus"},
                                new int[] { R.id.textViewPrice, R.id.textViewStatus});
                        setListAdapter(adapter);**
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

For the first listView, it's ok, but with the lines at the end (with the second adapter **) it fails. I don't know if I can use a second adapter like this...

How I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: this is bad idea hold one list in another, try one list with many linear layouts in row instead.

Comment: wrond idea but not impossible? otherwise, how I can do that with linerlayouts in row?

Comment: You will have problems with two scrollbars at the same time, consider using expandablelistview.

Comment: outer list has row layout with empty linear layout (or smth else), inner fake list has row layout as you want, in getView method of adapter you can dynamically create/inflate your view and add it to linear layout.

Comment: Ok. So, I have to use expandablelistview or linerlayouts in row?

Answer (score 0):

For liner layouts in row, Can I use this?

[Creating LinearLayout in Java - Elements are not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241145/creating-linearlayout-in-java-elements-are-not-shown)

But, at the end of this code, I can't do setContentView(layout), because my layout which containing my list will disappear. So how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)** ?

Nesting one ListView inside another may prove to be really troublesome. Especially handling the scroll events inside the child and the parent.

Yes, it may not be impossible, but why make your life hard ?